# getSchema in PostgreSQL JDBC driver throws java.lang.AbstractMethodError or java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, driver

I'm using Postgresql 8.4 and my application is trying to connect to the database.
I've registered the driver:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
```

and then trying the connection:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(database_url);
```

(btw, my jdbc string is something like: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myschema?user=myuser&password=mypassword)

I've tried various version of the jdbc driver and getting two type of errors:

with jdbc3:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;
```

with jdbc4:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Il metodo ½org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getSchema()╗ non Þ stato ancora implementato.
```

that means: method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.getSchema() not implemented yet.

I'm missing something but I don't know what..

------ SOLVED ---------

The problem were not in the connection String or the Driver version, the problem were in the code directly above the `getConnection()` method:

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(database_url);
LOGGER.info("Connected to : " + db.getCatalog() + " - " + db.getSchema());
```

It seems postgresql driver doesn't have `getSchema` method, as the java console were often trying to say to me..

Comment: What is the version of the driver you're using?  The filename of the jar contains the version number

Comment: I've used: 8.4-702.jdbc3, 8.4-702.jdbc4, 9.2-1002.jdbc3, 9.2-1002.jdbc4, 9.2-1003.jdbc3, 9.2-1003.jdbc4, 9.3-1102.jdbc3, 9.3-1102.jdbc4 and maybe a couple of other versions

Comment: Please show the full code of your test. Also, what's your JVM version?

Comment: Short version after discussion on comments - same error with `Class.forName`. Using JDK 1.7. So I think your classpath has multiple incompatible PgJDBC versions (possibly nested in other jars?) or something else is horribly broken. I'd need to see a standalone test case to help you further.

Comment: Now I'm using 9.3-1102-jdbc41, but I think that now that I've removed the problematic method ( db.getSchema() ) it could work also with other versions. java version 7.

Comment: Sources are [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), getSchema is indeed not implemented...

Comment: Yep, but the Connection interface has it, so the eclipse autocomplete showed the method and I used it without thinking too much.

Comment: You should **never** call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself for **normal** JDBC drivers; it is a hook for the `java.sql.Driver` implementations to register themselves with `DriverManager`.

Comment: In your comments in a now deleted answer you mention you use maven-shade, the could problem with that is that you did not include (or overwrote instead of merged) the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file which is necessary for JDBC 4 auto-loading.

Comment: @fvu getSchema is implemented for the next release: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blame/master/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#L255

Comment: I've checked that java.sql.Driver is contained in my jar in the directory you mentioned. Anyways, under your suggestion, I've changed DriverManager.registerDriver with Class.forName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Connection.getSchema()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema--) version was added in Java 7 / JDBC 4.1. This means that it is not necessarily available in a JDBC 3 or 4 driver (although if an implementation exists, it will get called).

If you use a JDBC 3 (Java 4/5) driver or a JDBC 4 (Java 6) driver in Java 7 or higher it is entirely possible that you receive a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` when calling `getSchema` if it **does not exist** in the implementation. Java provides a form of forward compatibility for classes implementing an interface.

If new methods are added to an interface, classes that do not have these methods and were - for example - compiled against an older version of the interface, can still be loaded and used provided the new methods are not called. Missing methods will be stubbed by code that simply throws an `AbstractMethodError`. On the other hand: if a method `getSchema` **had been implemented** and the signature was compatible that method would now be accessible through the interface, even though the method did not exist in the interface at compile time.

In [March 2011](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/4ea5d018e5ad1730bb4a721b00d1c231811f36f3), the driver was updated so it could be compiled on Java 7 (JDBC 4.1), this happened by stubbing the new JDBC 4.1 methods with an implementation that throws a `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`, including [the implementation of `Connection.getSchema`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/4ea5d018e5ad1730bb4a721b00d1c231811f36f3#diff-4d9af809da18b531504bcadb8383d1b4R211). This code is still in the current PostgreSQL JDBC driver version 9.3-1102. Technically a JDBC-compliant driver is not allowed to throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` unless the API documentation or JDBC specification explicitly allows it (which it doesn't for `getSchema`).

However the [current code](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blame/master/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#L255) on github does provide an implementation [since April this year](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/ea554581d8cb5499db4ab10c9af373f7f70dd583). You might want to consider compiling your own version, or ask on the pgsql-jdbc mailinglist if there are recent snapshots available (the snapshots link on http://jdbc.postgresql.org/ shows rather old versions).